# Why my Julia code runs slower than javascript?

Tags: performance, julia, benchmarking

Recently, I was intrigued by the Julia-lang as it claims to be a dynamic language that has near C performance. However, my experience with it so far is not good (at least performance wise).
The application that I'm writing requires random-access to specific array indices and then comparing their values with other specific array indices (over many iterations). The following code simulates my needs from the program:
My Julia code finishes executing in around 8seconds while the java-script code requires less than 1second on chrome environment! 
Am I doing something wrong with the Julia code? Thanks a lot in advance.

Julia code here:

```
n=5000;
x=rand(n)
y=rand(n)
mn=ones(n)*1000;
tic();
for i in 1:n;
    for j in 1:n;
        c=abs(x[j]-y[i]);
        if(c<mn[i])
            mn[i]=c;
        end
    end
end
toc();
```

Javascript code: (>8 times faster than the julia code above!)

```
n=5000; x=[]; y=[]; mn=[];
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){x.push(Math.random(1))}
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){y.push(Math.random(1))}
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){mn.push(1000)}
console.time('test');
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<n; j++){
        c=Math.abs(x[j]-y[i]);
        if(c<mn[i]){
            mn[i]=c;
        }       
    }
} 
console.timeEnd('test');
```

Comment: If you haven't already gleaned this from the (excellent) answers, please, if you read nothing else, read the [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/) section from the official docs. It will greatly help you in avoiding these performance gotchas, without requiring a deeper understanding of how the internals of Julia operate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed now I see where and how Julia shines over the JavaScript performance wise.

Comment: @Hunar are you compiling your js code with  node.js ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips)

> **Avoid global variables**
>
> A global variable might have its value, and therefore its type, change
>   at any point. This makes it difficult for the compiler to optimize
>   code using global variables. Variables should be local, or passed as
>   arguments to functions, whenever possible.
>
> Any code that is performance critical or being benchmarked should be
>   inside a function.
>
> We find that global names are frequently constants, and declaring them
>   as such greatly improves performance:

```rb
julia> const n = 5000; const x, y = rand(n), rand(n); const mn = fill(1000.0, n);

julia> function foo!(mn, x, y)
           n = length(mn)
           @inbounds for i in 1:n, j in 1:n
               c = abs(x[j] - y[i])
               if(c < mn[i])
                   mn[i] = c
               end
           end
           return mn
       end
foo! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> using BenchmarkTools: @btime

julia> @btime foo!(mn, x, y)
  15.432 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: *change at any point*: more specifically, as a possible side-effect of any (non-inline) function call, right?  Julia globals aren't like C++ `std::atomic` shared globals, are they, which can be changed asynchronously by other threads?  (I don't really know Julia, just casually curious.  But I think the performance advice is saying that the current compiler doesn't look for optimizations on globals even when the only function call is `abs()`, which should be built-in and can inline.  So it's a missed optimization in the current compiler, right?  And thus still good advice.)

Comment: Not an expert, but I think that the problem is that if the *kind* of value hold by a variable can change at any moment (i.e. in each function call) then you cannot just use the abs function that takes an Int (and then optimized for 'Int's, because you cannot know it will be an Int. So you still have to call the "generic", check the type, and then run the right one. Also, you aren't even sure on the result type of map, because it could change (when abs function is changed). The compiler cannot optimize things he cannot infer

Comment: Not an expert either, but I think the issue of changing at any point comes from everything being a function call, and everything being overrideable. `-` is a function call, so are `<` and `x[j]` and even `=` IIRC. `x[j]` is really `getindex(x, i)`, which can theoretically be overridden in your code to mutate x (though that's obviously an awful idea). It's still a missed optimization in that the compiler can be given knowledge of non-mutating builtins, verify they're not overridden and optimise based on that, but it's non trivial and comes with its own issues.

Answer (score 4):

Julia code should always be inside a function, so that the compiler can optimize it. Also, you are measuring both the compile time and the execution time: to get an accurate measure, you should call the function twice (the first for compilation).

```
function test(n)
    x=rand(n);
    y=rand(n);
    mn=ones(n)*1000;

    for i in 1:n;
        for j in 1:n;
            c=abs(x[j]-y[i])
            if(c<mn[i])
                mn[i]=c
            end
        end
    end
    (mn, x, y)
end

test(1)
@time test(5000);
```

This is taking 0.04s on my laptop. javascript in chromium 1s
(javascript in firefox web console 53s)

Comment: Exactly. Additionally you can add `@inbounds` annotation of for loops and move creation of `x`, `y` and `mn` outside function and pass them (to have the same amount of work as in JavaScript code). Finally if you run `@time ...` for the second time the execution time should be even faster as you will not pay compilation cost.