# Viewing lowered version of Julia code that's not in a function

Tags: julia

I was reading [this question about performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50140490/8127) involving global variables, and wanted to see how exactly Julia translates this code. I realized then that `code_warntype` can't be used in the usual way here since the code isn't in a function, and wrapping it in a function would defeat the whole point of the exercise.

Is there an analogue or another version of `@code_warntype` that will take some Julia code directly (eg. as a filename, or as a plain string) and show us the typed lowered version of that code? Or perhaps a command line flag that outputs lowered code? (There seemed to be flags for generating LLVM code or object files, but none for outputting code that's just type inferred and lowered.)

Comment: Are you looking for @code_lowered maybe?

Comment: How do I send the code to `@code_lowered` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can always wrap the code in question into a function and call `@code_warntype` on that.

Here's an example for the linked question:

```
n=5000;
x=rand(n)
y=rand(n)
mn=ones(n)*1000;
function foo()
    for i in 1:n;
        for j in 1:n;
            c=abs(x[j]-y[i]);
            if(c<mn[i])
                mn[i]=c;
            end
        end
    end
end

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #temp#@_2::Any
  i::Any
  #temp#@_4::Any
  j::Any
  c::Any

Body:
  begin
      Core.SSAValue(0) = (1:Main.n)::Any
      #temp#@_2::Any = (Base.start)(Core.SSAValue(0))::Any
      3: 
      Core.SSAValue(1) = (Base.done)(Core.SSAValue(0), #temp#@_2::Any)::Any
      Core.SSAValue(2) = (Core.typeassert)(Core.SSAValue(1), Core.Bool)::Bool
      Core.SSAValue(3) = (Base.not_int)(Core.SSAValue(2))::Bool
      unless Core.SSAValue(3) goto 37
      Core.SSAValue(4) = (Base.next)(Core.SSAValue(0), #temp#@_2::Any)::Any
      i::Any = (Core.getfield)(Core.SSAValue(4), 1)::Any
      #temp#@_2::Any = (Core.getfield)(Core.SSAValue(4), 2)::Any
      #= line 2 =#
      Core.SSAValue(5) = (1:Main.n)::Any
      #temp#@_4::Any = (Base.start)(Core.SSAValue(5))::Any
      14: 
      Core.SSAValue(6) = (Base.done)(Core.SSAValue(5), #temp#@_4::Any)::Any
      Core.SSAValue(7) = (Core.typeassert)(Core.SSAValue(6), Core.Bool)::Bool
      Core.SSAValue(8) = (Base.not_int)(Core.SSAValue(7))::Bool
      unless Core.SSAValue(8) goto 35
      Core.SSAValue(9) = (Base.next)(Core.SSAValue(5), #temp#@_4::Any)::Any
      j::Any = (Core.getfield)(Core.SSAValue(9), 1)::Any
      #temp#@_4::Any = (Core.getfield)(Core.SSAValue(9), 2)::Any
      #= line 3 =#
      Core.SSAValue(10) = (Base.getindex)(Main.x, j::Any)::Any
      Core.SSAValue(11) = (Base.getindex)(Main.y, i::Any)::Any
      Core.SSAValue(12) = (Core.SSAValue(10) - Core.SSAValue(11))::Any
      c::Any = (Main.abs)(Core.SSAValue(12))::Any
      #= line 5 =#
      Core.SSAValue(14) = (Base.getindex)(Main.mn, i::Any)::Any
      Core.SSAValue(15) = (c::Any < Core.SSAValue(14))::Any
      unless Core.SSAValue(15) goto 33
      #= line 6 =#
      (Base.setindex!)(Main.mn, c::Any, i::Any)::Any
      33: 
      goto 14
      35: 
      goto 3
      37: 
      return
  end::Nothing
```

Compare the above with

```
function foo()
    n=5000;
    x=rand(n)
    y=rand(n)
    mn=ones(n)*1000;
    for i in 1:n;
        for j in 1:n;
            c=abs(x[j]-y[i]);
            if(c<mn[i])
                mn[i]=c;
            end
        end
    end
end

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  n<optimized out>
  x<optimized out>
  y<optimized out>
  mn::Array{Float64,1}
  #temp#@_6::Int64
  i<optimized out>
  #temp#@_8::Int64
  j<optimized out>
  c<optimized out>
  #temp#@_13::Bool
  #temp#@_16::Bool

Body:
  begin
      #= line 3 =#
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 224
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 236
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 235
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 397
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 389
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 380
      Core.SSAValue(46) = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), :(:ccall), 2, Array{Float64,1}, 5000, 5000))
      # meta: pop locations (3)
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand! 214
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl rand! 447
      # meta: location array.jl length 137
      Core.SSAValue(53) = (Base.arraylen)(Core.SSAValue(46))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl _rand! 440
      # meta: location int.jl * 54
      Core.SSAValue(66) = (Base.mul_int)(8, Core.SSAValue(53))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location array.jl length 137
      Core.SSAValue(67) = (Base.arraylen)(Core.SSAValue(46))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location int.jl * 54
      Core.SSAValue(68) = (Base.mul_int)(8, Core.SSAValue(67))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location int.jl <= 419
      Core.SSAValue(69) = (Base.sle_int)(Core.SSAValue(66), Core.SSAValue(68))::Bool
      # meta: pop location
      unless Core.SSAValue(69) goto 31
      #temp#@_13::Bool = true
      goto 33
      31: 
      #temp#@_13::Bool = false
      33: 
      unless #temp#@_13::Bool goto 36
      goto 41
      36: 
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 281
      Core.SSAValue(71) = $(Expr(:new, :(Core.AssertionError), "sizeof(Float64) * n64 <= sizeof(T) * length(A) && isbits(T)"))
      # meta: pop location
      (Base.throw)(Core.SSAValue(71))::Union{}
      41: 
      #= line 441 =#
      # meta: location gcutils.jl
      #= line 81 =#
      Core.SSAValue(61) = $(Expr(:gc_preserve_begin, Core.SSAValue(46)))
      #= line 82 =#
      # meta: location abstractarray.jl pointer 911
      # meta: location pointer.jl unsafe_convert 65
      Core.SSAValue(74) = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_array_ptr), Ptr{Float64}, svec(Any), :(:ccall), 1, Core.SSAValue(46)))
      # meta: pop locations (2)
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl Type 365
      Core.SSAValue(79) = $(Expr(:new, Random.UnsafeView{Float64}, Core.SSAValue(74), Core.SSAValue(53)))
      # meta: pop location
      $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand!(::Random.MersenneTwister, ::Random.UnsafeView{Float64}, ::Random.SamplerTrivial{Random.CloseOpen01{Float64},Float64}), :(Random.rand!), :(Random.GLOBAL_RNG), Core.SSAValue(79), :($(QuoteNode(Random.SamplerTrivial{Random.CloseOpen01{Float64},Float64}(Random.CloseOpen01{Float64}()))))))::Random.UnsafeView{Float64}
      #= line 83 =#
      $(Expr(:gc_preserve_end, Core.SSAValue(61)))
      # meta: pop locations (7)
      #= line 4 =#
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 224
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 236
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand 235
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 397
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 389
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 380
      Core.SSAValue(109) = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), :(:ccall), 2, Array{Float64,1}, 5000, 5000))
      # meta: pop locations (3)
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/Random.jl rand! 214
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl rand! 447
      # meta: location array.jl length 137
      Core.SSAValue(116) = (Base.arraylen)(Core.SSAValue(109))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl _rand! 440
      # meta: location int.jl * 54
      Core.SSAValue(129) = (Base.mul_int)(8, Core.SSAValue(116))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location array.jl length 137
      Core.SSAValue(130) = (Base.arraylen)(Core.SSAValue(109))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location int.jl * 54
      Core.SSAValue(131) = (Base.mul_int)(8, Core.SSAValue(130))::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location int.jl <= 419
      Core.SSAValue(132) = (Base.sle_int)(Core.SSAValue(129), Core.SSAValue(131))::Bool
      # meta: pop location
      unless Core.SSAValue(132) goto 88
      #temp#@_16::Bool = true
      goto 90
      88: 
      #temp#@_16::Bool = false
      90: 
      unless #temp#@_16::Bool goto 93
      goto 98
      93: 
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 281
      Core.SSAValue(134) = $(Expr(:new, :(Core.AssertionError), "sizeof(Float64) * n64 <= sizeof(T) * length(A) && isbits(T)"))
      # meta: pop location
      (Base.throw)(Core.SSAValue(134))::Union{}
      98: 
      #= line 441 =#
      # meta: location gcutils.jl
      #= line 81 =#
      Core.SSAValue(124) = $(Expr(:gc_preserve_begin, Core.SSAValue(109)))
      #= line 82 =#
      # meta: location abstractarray.jl pointer 911
      # meta: location pointer.jl unsafe_convert 65
      Core.SSAValue(137) = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_array_ptr), Ptr{Float64}, svec(Any), :(:ccall), 1, Core.SSAValue(109)))
      # meta: pop locations (2)
      # meta: location /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/site/v0.7/Random/src/RNGs.jl Type 365
      Core.SSAValue(142) = $(Expr(:new, Random.UnsafeView{Float64}, Core.SSAValue(137), Core.SSAValue(116)))
      # meta: pop location
      $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand!(::Random.MersenneTwister, ::Random.UnsafeView{Float64}, ::Random.SamplerTrivial{Random.CloseOpen01{Float64},Float64}), :(Random.rand!), :(Random.GLOBAL_RNG), Core.SSAValue(142), :($(QuoteNode(Random.SamplerTrivial{Random.CloseOpen01{Float64},Float64}(Random.CloseOpen01{Float64}()))))))::Random.UnsafeView{Float64}
      #= line 83 =#
      $(Expr(:gc_preserve_end, Core.SSAValue(124)))
      # meta: pop locations (7)
      #= line 5 =#
      # meta: location array.jl ones 398
      # meta: location array.jl ones 396
      # meta: location array.jl ones 395
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 389
      # meta: location boot.jl Type 380
      Core.SSAValue(170) = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), :(:ccall), 2, Array{Float64,1}, 5000, 5000))
      # meta: pop locations (2)
      Core.SSAValue(151) = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for fill!(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64), :(Base.fill!), Core.SSAValue(170), 1.0))::Array{Float64,1}
      # meta: pop locations (3)
      mn::Array{Float64,1} = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for *(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64), :(Main.:*), Core.SSAValue(151), 1000))::Array{Float64,1}
      #= line 6 =#
      #temp#@_6::Int64 = 1
      128: 
      # meta: location range.jl done 457
      # meta: location int.jl + 53
      Core.SSAValue(197) = (Base.add_int)(5000, 1)::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location promotion.jl == 433
      Core.SSAValue(198) = (#temp#@_6::Int64 === Core.SSAValue(197))::Bool
      # meta: pop locations (2)
      Core.SSAValue(4) = (Base.not_int)(Core.SSAValue(198))::Bool
      unless Core.SSAValue(4) goto 193
      # meta: location range.jl next 456
      # meta: location int.jl + 53
      Core.SSAValue(203) = (Base.add_int)(#temp#@_6::Int64, 1)::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      Core.SSAValue(246) = #temp#@_6::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      #temp#@_6::Int64 = Core.SSAValue(203)
      #= line 6 =#
      #temp#@_8::Int64 = 1
      147: 
      # meta: location range.jl done 457
      # meta: location int.jl + 53
      Core.SSAValue(229) = (Base.add_int)(5000, 1)::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location promotion.jl == 433
      Core.SSAValue(230) = (#temp#@_8::Int64 === Core.SSAValue(229))::Bool
      # meta: pop locations (2)
      Core.SSAValue(9) = (Base.not_int)(Core.SSAValue(230))::Bool
      unless Core.SSAValue(9) goto 191
      # meta: location range.jl next 456
      # meta: location int.jl + 53
      Core.SSAValue(235) = (Base.add_int)(#temp#@_8::Int64, 1)::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      Core.SSAValue(245) = #temp#@_8::Int64
      # meta: pop location
      #temp#@_8::Int64 = Core.SSAValue(235)
      #= line 7 =#
      # meta: location array.jl getindex 661
      Core.SSAValue(236) = (Base.arrayref)(true, Core.SSAValue(46), Core.SSAValue(245))::Float64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location array.jl getindex 661
      Core.SSAValue(237) = (Base.arrayref)(true, Core.SSAValue(109), Core.SSAValue(246))::Float64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location float.jl - 395
      Core.SSAValue(238) = (Base.sub_float)(Core.SSAValue(236), Core.SSAValue(237))::Float64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location float.jl abs 517
      Core.SSAValue(239) = (Base.abs_float)(Core.SSAValue(238))::Float64
      # meta: pop location
      #= line 9 =#
      # meta: location array.jl getindex 661
      Core.SSAValue(240) = (Base.arrayref)(true, mn::Array{Float64,1}, Core.SSAValue(246))::Float64
      # meta: pop location
      # meta: location float.jl < 450
      Core.SSAValue(241) = (Base.lt_float)(Core.SSAValue(239), Core.SSAValue(240))::Bool
      # meta: pop location
      unless Core.SSAValue(241) goto 189
      #= line 10 =#
      # meta: location array.jl setindex! 699
      (Base.arrayset)(true, mn::Array{Float64,1}, Core.SSAValue(239), Core.SSAValue(246))::Array{Float64,1}
      # meta: pop location
      189: 
      goto 147
      191: 
      goto 128
      193: 
      return
  end::Nothing
```

Comment: Of course, that's an easy option, but: (a) it doesn't really generate the same code it would when there's no function wrapping it. The difference in this case might be minimal and predictable, but in more complex and varied code it would get hard to track; and (b) it doesn't show the generated code for lines outside the function, which again might be more complex than in this example. The more we try to mitigate issue-(b) by wrapping things inside the function, the more significant issue-(a) becomes.

Comment: I agree with your point in principle, but in practice I have not yet encountered a case where I wasn't happy with my workaround. I'll leave this question for someone with a more solid understanding of how code not wrapped in a function gets evaluated, then.

Comment: I understand that, for practical production code I wouldn't need anything more either, but in this case it's for pedagogical and academic purposes that I'm interested in this. The question itself is intended as an "in principle" question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the lowered form of top level code, the answer is to use `Meta.lower()` or `Meta.@lower`